# Xamarin.Messaging.Broker wants firewall access

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

After installing VS2019 16.5.1 and 16.5.2 I receive a message that Windows Defender has locked some features of `Xamarin.Messaging.Broker` and asking if I should allow it.

Normally I would as it seems to be part of Visual Studio but this executable is located in my appdata\local\temp file, which I would not expect it to be. Searching the net for info about this yields little in the way of good information.

Does anyoe know what it does and why on earth would you put an exe in the local user temp?

Comment: Hi , you mean before 16.5.1 it not wants firewall access ,right ?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug in a recent VS update? I had the same issue, and searching for it only turned up this recent question of yours.

Comment: I got this message out of nowhere even though I use VS daily, I haven't updated VS in a couple weeks, and I don't even have a Xamarin project currently running.

Comment: Me too, Post Impatica.   Maybe we should post it to an MS forum.

Comment: I got this message first time today in VS2022 17.1.2. After I clicked up the Toolbox window for the first time in years.

Comment: Same here, v17.1.2... what's funny (and sad) is an MS _employee_ posted this as an issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/asks-for-network-request-permission-when-opening-t/1167297) and was blown off with "closed-not a bug" and effectively zero useful information (in badly broken English). I guess it's "nice" to know that we "little people" aren't the only ones who get the cold shoulder on VS issues.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My message appear exactly after upgrade 16.5.0 to 16.5.3, We all see this message in 16.5.2 version and above.

So as far as we know this happened because microsoft add something new in 16.5.2 and above, It can't be anything except microsoft work since we all have seen this firewall message.

My file was in C:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\xamarin\xma\broker.local\16.5.000.533\broker.exe

This access will add a record in firewall advanced "Inbound Rules" Which means grant an access from outside to our PCs on UDP/TCP.

**Conclusion :**

Personaly i allowd this file in firewall because i have tons of problems in xamarin (special to connect to Mac) and i don't want to add more, I suggest you all do the same.

Comment: *Personaly i allowd this file in firewall because i have tons of problems in xamarin (special to connect to Mac) and i don't want to add more, I suggest you all do the same.*

Cannot disagree with that logic :)

Comment: Still an issue with the path "%USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\xamarin\xma\local\broker\17.2.0.177\broker.exe". I don't use Xamarin directly, but I got the request for access when I started using Simple.Wpf.Terminal.

Comment: Why is it necessary to allow the firewall access? i.e. what won't you be able to achieve if you deny access? Also the q about an exe in the local temp dir is still outstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it would be in that location, but this article lists the endpoints to allow for a xamarin firewall configuration. Perhaps it might assist in some way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/installation/firewall

Comment: That article is about outbound connections. It does not explain why the Xamarin Broker needs to allow inbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022 I just had this security alert just as I went to open the toolbox to add a Button to a new WPF project.

```
**Windows Defender Firewall has blocked some features of this app**

Name: Broker
Publisher: Xamarin
Path: C:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\xamarin\xma\local\broker\17.3.0.288\broker.exe

Allow Broker to communicate on these networks:
✔ Private networks, such as my home or work network
```

I refused it.

Comment: Seems Visual Studio 2022 also open this firewall Popup. Seems I had the same issue